# Outbound sales call center data

Tags: data-request

Is there an open / available data set that covers the operations of a outbound sales call center. The intention is to look at some of the following question

- Sales per person per hour
- Successful contacts vs non successfull contacts
- How many are quick vs slow failures. e.g. immediate hangup vs no sale after spending some time
- How much individuals effect the result

Even if i could get the top 3 it would be of interest.

Comment: Have you had any luck in finding this data?

Comment: @CordovanSaviour no nothing public